# How do I make an image look dark in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photoshop-effects

Can anyone give me an idea of the filter used on this image:

[image: http://demo.themeum.com/html/oxygen/images/features-bg.jpg]

**What I have tried**

1) Add a black layer above my image and set the opacity to 60% - this darkens the image.

2) On the image itself: adjustments > Gradient Map > Foreground to background (reversed) for colours #ffffff to #a3261a.

I have Photoshop CS3 and i'm looking to copy this effect but don't know how.  I'm a developer, not a designer, so not realy sure what tutorial to google for :)

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Scott, have you tried anything on your own? What makes you think this is a "filter" of some sort? All I see is a darkened photograph.

Comment: it says i cant comment as i dont have "50 reputation"... I have tried 2 things 1) add a black layer above my image and set the opacity to 60% - this darkens the image
2) on the image itself: adjustments > Gradient Map > Foreground to background (reversed) for colours #ffffff to #a3261a

Comment: Have you tried playing with the Levels? The darkened bright areas (sky, highlights) and the high contrast feel suggest that Levels might do the trick.

Comment: Also, if you show the original image and what you get when you try your own methods, it would be better to suggest alternatives.

Comment: The image above is modified from an already processed image. You can see an example here [http://img.freepik.com/free-photo/chained-bicycle_430-19315495.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg](http://img.freepik.com/free-photo/chained-bicycle_430-19315495.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg). To get the above effect from the original edited photo you just add a black layer above it and make it ~40%. If you're asking how to get the old-desaturated photo effect, then you should reword your question.

Answer (score 3):

Having found the "original" of this image, I placed it below your example...

[image]

By adding a black layer over top (as you did) and reducing its opacity to 50% as well as increasing the master saturation of the original image by 10%, I was able to achieve a nearly pixel-perfect duplicate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In design, there isn't one single way to achieve whatever outcome it is you're looking at. However, some methods are more effective than others. To get the above effect, try these steps:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to duplicate the image layer
2. Click on the top layer and change the blend mode to either Multiply or Overlay
3. Go to Image > Adjustments > Levels
4. Adjust the middle node (*sliding right makes darker image, sliding left makes lighter image*) till you get your desired outcome.

Comment: Sliding the middle node did nothing for me (image is https://unsplash.com/photos/2QyUwJloE7w)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a black layer try picking up a darker tone from the image and try various opacity percentage. You should reach close to the look you are seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Add "Darken" blend mode to that layer, it will help you make light areas darker. Play with transparency when you apply this to tweak intensity.

Comment: Had no effect on the image I'm working with (https://unsplash.com/photos/2QyUwJloE7w)

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional advice to all the others; 
Alot say 'play with Gradient' etc. I also suggest you try and "play" alittle with the hue/saturation - especially the 'hue' in your case.
You'll be amazed at how many different things you can do with changing these scales :)

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Can you expand your answer to explain how hue and saturation would create the effect? If you want to know more about the site, please see [the help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Well Saturation might not do that much except make the blackness more visible. 
But by changing the Hue curve you can darken the image for sure.